# Invalid MXD Filename error in one script, but not the other

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, mxd

I have created 2 geometric trace models for a project, one to pick a spot on the network and run an isolation, and the other to choose from a list of buildings, then then run a trace to find features to isolate that building. Both models use a python script at the end to combine all outputs from multiple group layers into one out feature class for each participating feature class in the network. Also, both models reference the same MXD file in order to used some arcpy.mapping functions.

I published the network iso model on the server and it runs just fine with no errors both on ArcMap and the WebApp I made on ArcGIS online. When i publish the building iso model, it fails with a "invalid MXD Filename" error. The whole output can be seen below.

[image]

Both models uses the *exact* same script, yet it only fails on the building iso model and not the network iso model. I even tried saving a copy of the MXD as a different name, but still received the same error. the part of the script that is failing can be seen below.

[image]

The filepath does not have any special characters in it, and again, works just fine in the other model. Has anyone ran into this problem before? I have been looking around blogs and ESRI resource sites but haven't found anything to help. One odd thing i did notice is that the line the log reports the error occurring on is not the same line number as it is in the original script, but i'm not sure if that means anything.

@KHibma provided help. I found out the script is not copying the MXD file to the server, even though it say it is when publishing. Also, it does not seem  to be setting the variables correctly on the server. in the picture below, the script on the left is the network iso, and the right is the building iso.

Why isn't the publishing tools correctly formatting the script from the building iso model?

All the parameters are set the same as in the network iso model.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the statement it says it is failing on (diff from original script)?

Comment: Do you mean for the network iso script? It is the exactly the same, with the exception of 2 more input parameters.

Comment: Can you confirm the MXD got copied to the server and is properly being referenced? You'll need to do some manual poking around. On the server, navigate to C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\BuildingShotOff.GPServer\extracted and drill into the folder with the script. At the top of the script, the g_ESRI_variable1 will point to the location of the MXD. Make sure 1) its there and 2) you can open it.

Comment: @KHibma It is not. When i publish it, it says it is copying the MXD to the server, but i guess it is not. Can i just change the g_ESRI_variable1 name to the same line as the network iso script and copy the MXD file over as well?

Comment: and also, why isn't it copying the MXD onto the server?

Comment: @Lou you can move it to the server (along with the data inside of it) or update the line in that script and it'll start to work. But thats a bit of a hack. You said 1 version works, the other does not -- From your screenshots it looks like you may have registered the folder (your Desktop) with the datastore between the time you published the 1st and 2nd?

Comment: No I have nothing registered in the servers datastore right now

Comment: I dont have enough information to explain why its happened. To me it seems like its registered, as you see the path to the original location. Are you passing in or referencing the MXD differently from one script to another?

Comment: No, they are exact copies with the exception of added parameters for the building iso. I found an error in flow direction, so i had to republish the network iso model, and now it has the same issue. The MXD is not getting copied to the server. I tried restarting both arcmap and the server itself to no avail. I also tried creating a entirely new MXD file, but that did not work either.

Comment: Please always include the text of your code snippets and error messages rather than pictures because text helps both potential answerers to help you and future searches to find similar error messages and coding patterns.